# Checking email while updating the user?

Tags: django, authentication

Here i have two forms for adding and updating user.The Register form is working fine to check if the email already exists but while updating the user it is not working properly.The problem is  When i do update the username only it also says the email address already exists.What i want is while updating the user if only the user change the email address and the changed email address is already in use then i want to raise validation error.How can i do that ?

> forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    def check_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Email Already Exists')
        return email

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', "email", "password1", "password2", 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active']


class EditRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def check_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        email_exists = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk and not email_exists
            return email

        else:
             raise ValidationError('Email already Exists')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', "email", 'is_superuser','is_staff', 'is_active']
```

Comment: In `check_email` method use `email_exists = User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()`

Comment: i have done that already.Before i t was `if self.instance and self.instance.pk and not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():` But the result was same

Comment: Is it return email not ValidationError('Email already Exists')?

Comment: yes  it throws validation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
email_exists = User.objects.filter(email=email)
```

is matching with the current user's email address, hence it's triggering the "email already exists" validation error.

To avoid this, just exclude the current user from the queryset.

```
email_exists = User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change logic here

```
if self.instance and self.instance.pk and User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    return email
```

Comment: @xyres answer helps in this case